# Descendent / Ancestor query

Tags: data-structures

I already looked at my book many times, but I'm confused about one definition. In my data structures and algorithms book, I have the following definition:

A node u is an **ancestor** of a node v if u = v or u is an ancestor of the parent of v. Conversely, we say that a node is a **descendent** of a node u if u is an ancestor of v.

What is the first part of the definition saying? Does it mean that a node only has two ancestors, itself (u = v) and the parent of it's parent (the parent of v)?

Answer (score 0):

> A node u is an **ancestor** of a node v if u = v or u is an ancestor of the parent of v.

This is a recursive definition, and means that the ancestors of a node are the node itself together with the node's parent and all the parent's ancestors.

The fact that the parent's ancestors are defined by the same definition is what makes it recursive, and what makes, for example, the parent's parent also an ancestor.

Perhaps a walk-through of a structure applying this definition will help.

Consider the tree:

```
     A
   /   \
  B     C  
 /     / \  
D     E   F  
     /  
    G
```

If we want to find all ancestors of node *G*, we apply the definition:

*G* itself is an ancestor, and as *E* is *G*'s parent, all of *E*'s ancestors are also ancestors of *G*.

This means in order to find all ancestors of *G* we must find all ancestors of *E*.

Again, by the definition *E* itself is an ancestor of *E* and therefore also of *G*, as are all ancestors of *E*'s parent, *C*.

So we have to find all ancestors of *C*!

Again applying the definition, *C* is an ancestor of itself, and thus of both *E* and *G*.  And the ancestors of *C*'s parent *A* are as well.

So we have to find all ancestors of *A*!

Well, by the definition *A* is its own ancestor, and as it has no parent, it has no other ancestors.

So then, having reached a terminating condition, the recursion sends us back through the stack for the result ...

*C* has the ancestors *C* (itself) and *A* (all the parent *A*'s ancestors).

*E* has the ancestors *E* (itself) and *C*, *A* (all the parent *C*'s ancestors).

*G has the ancestors *G* (itself) and *E*, *C*, *A* (all the parent *E*'s ancestors).

I hope this makes it more clear, but, as they say, "In order to understand recursion, you must first understand recursion."

Comment: Thank you for your answer Don. I'm still fuzzy on the recursion. I understand that u = v is the base case (i.e. the node u is its own ancestor). But this "u is an ancestor of the parent of v" still gets me.

Comment: My understanding is that we look at a node v. It's its own ancestor. Then we look at its parent. The parent is its own ancestor, So by the transitive property: the parent is the ancestor of the child. And this goes on forever? Once again, thank you!

Comment: Can't do it now, as I'm at work, but perhaps later I'll add a walkthrough of an example.